# How to get the sum of an Integer arraylist?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, sum, java.util.scanner

Basically Im trying to make a program that allows a teacher to input grades for a test for each student then after they've inputted the grades it gives the teacher a sum of all the grades they inputted

```
public static void grades(){
    List<Integer> grade = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int gradetotal = IntStream.of(grades).sum;/* sum */
    int gradelistnumber = 1;
    int inputedgrade = 0;

    while(inputedgrade != -1){
        System.out.println("Enter Grade for student " + gradelistnumber + " (1-50): ");
        inputedgrade = sc.nextInt();
        grade.add(inputedgrade);
        gradelistnumber++;


    }

    System.out.println("Class Average: " + gradetotal / 50 * 100);
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to get the sum of the array list *grades* .

Comment: you need to show us an example of what you have tried.

Comment: Have you looked at the API for ArrayList yet?

Comment: *Just added it but it doesnt seem to work with an array list*

Comment: Also, your value gradelistnumber will show 1 greater than the actual number of grades in the arraylist. You do not need a variable for this as the ArrayList API has methods (variable) for finding the count.

Comment: @azurefrog Yes, I have haven't I did not find anything for getting the sum.

Comment: @Ibounes just do a for loop and add the value of each item to a variable (total). Then divide this by the total number of items. Us writing your for-loop for you will teach you nothing.

Comment: @Ibounes you are adding each time a grade to a list. Doesn't this help you on how to sum them?

Comment: @MattJones The gradelistnumber isnt for getting the number of grades its the number of students for example Student 1's grade. There isnt a student 0. So I want it to be one above.

Comment: @Ibounes Ahh yes, my apologies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how you sum a Collection using java 8:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
        numbers.add(1);
        numbers.add(3);
        numbers.add(5);

        System.out.println(numbers.stream().mapToInt(value -> value).sum());
    }
}
```

In your code, you would do this to the `grade` list.  You can set this to `gradetotal` *after* your loop.

`value -> value` is saying "take each argument and return it".  `stream()` returns a `Stream` which doesn't have `sum()`.  `mapToInt` returns an `IntStream` which **does** have `sum()`.  That `value -> value` tells the code how to convert each element in the `Stream` into an `Integer`.  Because each element is *already* an `Integer`, we merely have to return each element.

Comment: Or much simpler: `numbers.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).sum();`

Comment: @assylias nice, I'm not too familiar with the new Java 8 APIs, I'll update.

Comment: @assylias it's very odd to me that I can't pass `Function.identity()` into `mapToInt`.

Comment: @tieTYT if you want to avoid the auto unboxing you can use `mapToInt(Integer::intValue)`. With Function.identity you could use `Function.<Integer>identity()::apply` which is kind of ugly (and not sure why we need to set the target type explicitly in that case).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of maintaining an array, why not just keep two temporary variables - a count and a summation?

```
int gradetotal = 0;
int gradelistnumber = 0;
int inputedgrade = 0;
while(inputedgrade != -1){
    System.out.println("Enter Grade for student " + gradelistnumber + " (1-50): ");
    inputedgrade = sc.nextInt();
    gradetotal = gradetotal + inputedgrade;
    gradelistnumber++;
}
```